How to literally translate this: 包括家人在内的任何人他都一律不见?
在这一周的时间里，他会把自己关在一所房子里，包括家人在内的任何人他都一律不见，使自己完全不受日常工作的打扰。
This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, segment 26.
How to literally translate this: 包括家人在内的任何人他都一律不见?
包括(including)家人(family)在内的(including)任何人(anyone)他(he)都(all)一律(equally)不见(not to see)
As you can see, it doesn't make sense to me. Especially the two different includings perplex me.

包括家人在内的任何人(anyone including members of the family)他(he)都(all)一律(alike/without exception/indiscriminately)不见(refuse to see)，

All, without exception, he refuses to see anyone including members of the family.

Note that "word-to-word translation" often fails to deliver the true meaning. We shall always try to put the translated words in the order that makes sense in the destination language. Also, "a word" sometimes can have more than one meaning/interpretation, to choose the most appropriate interpretation is like putting the puzzle together. Have fun :)

The same question that I asked to @Pedroski. So this: 包括家人在内 is like this: 在家里? 在 ... 里 means in, so 包括...在内 means including or do I miss something?

包括家人在内的任何人 = 任何人, 包括家人在内 - including anyone, family members included. The word "included" here means "anyone, inclusive of family members". Or you may say, "including anyone, inclusive of family members". Hope this makes sense.

So mathematically speaking, it is something like: 包括［家人在内］的任何人. So he wanted to write: 包括任何人 = including anyone. But then he wanted to emphasize "even the family" and it bacame 包括［家人在内］的任何人 = including [inclusive of family members] anyone. Am I right?

Yes, you got it :)

包括: including
家人: family
在内: in
的任何人: anybody
他: he
都: all
一律: equally
不见: not see, receive
在这一周的时间里，
For one week,
他会把自己关在一所房子里，
he will shut himself in a room,
包括家人在内的任何人他都一律不见，
(and) including family, he will ignore any and all,
使自己完全不受日常工作的打扰。
in order to completely avoid (the usual) daily disturbances.

So this: 包括家人在内 is like this: 在家里? 在 ... 里 means in, so 包括...在内 means including or do I miss something?

包括家人在内 including family 任何人 anyone 他 he 都 all 一律 the same 不见 not see

I still don't understand. What I should search in dictionaries? 包括...在内? Why are both needed? Isn't one enough? 包括家人的任何人他都一律不见? 家人在内的任何人他都一律不见? Don't both make the same sense?

Quote:- " 包括...在内? Why are both needed? Isn't one enough?" Yes & No. In every language there is colloquial speech and good stylistic writings. In the former, 包括家人 & 家人在内 may be acceptable, (depending on the company you keep) However, in academic essay writings, 包括...在内 shows a better scholastic understanding of the Chinese language. Assuming you are writing the sentence in your question, you will score better marks with 包括...在内 which at your Level of HSK5 is being introduced to better forms of essay writing. So, accept that that is how the language works and so learn it for your betterment.

And, hopefully, in the near future when you are better acquainted with the language, you will realize and appreciate that 包括家人在内 sounds so much better, whether written or spoken, than 包括家人 & 家人在内.

Why are both needed? Chinese likes to wrap phrases at both ends. Expect that. 在桌子上, 在这种情况下 In English we say: included in, concomitant with, outside of. Perhaps the English should not do this, but it is how we speak!

Perhaps OP feels that 包括家人在内 would be translated literally as "...included within it family members", which, besides being redundant, also sounds 'off"?
